# jQuery/Javascript NaN when doing addition on number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to create a simple link scroller but run into some trouble working out the current position.

Basically, in my code I've initialised the currentPos variable outside of the function. Then try to add 1 to it but I'm getting some erratic behaviour. Sometimes getting NaN.

This is on a localhost xampp installation, the same code works fine in jsfiddle so I can't understand it.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w654X/

My code is below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var currentPos = 1;

$('#test').click(function() {
    // exit if animation is already playing
    if ($(':animated').length) {
        return false;
    }

    height = $('#inner').height();
    noOfLinks = height / 53;
    lastPos = noOfLinks - 4;

    alert(currentPos);

    if (currentPos != lastPos) {
        $('#inner').animate({
            marginTop: "-=106px"
        });
    } 
    else {
        $('.arrow-up').hide();
    }

    currentPos += 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this has driven me crazy for far too long but it turns out that I had already used the variable name 'direction' in another script. Used different names and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var currentPos = 1;
$('#test').click(function() {

// exit if animation is already playing
    if ($(':animated').length) {
        return false;
    }

height = $('#inner').height();
noOfLinks = height / 53;
lastPos = noOfLinks - 4;

alert(currentPos);

if (currentPos != lastPos) {
    $('#inner').animate({
        marginTop: "-=106px"
    });
} else {
    $('.arrow-up').hide();
}

currentPos += 1;

});
});
```

Let me know where you have used the script in load or document ready perivously.

Thanks

Comment: Same thing, it's just so erratic, there doesn't appear to be any pattern to it either. I'm sure this is just a weird problem on my end because I can't see an error in the code. I was using it in jQuery document ready already.